# how to get the selected item value and do something after item been selected in php

Tags: php, html, events

i have got this code which query the database and populate a dropdown list
first: i want to make sure this code set the value of the item to the ID retrieved 
second: i want to populate another dropdown list upon the previous selected item

code looks like this

```
<?php
 $query="SELECT * FROM city ORDER BY ID";
 $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
 $options = array();
  while ($query_data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $options[$query_data["ID"]] = $query_data["Cname"];
  }
  ?>
      <select name="dropdown_city" >
 <?php foreach ($options as $key => $value) : ?>
<?php $selected = ($key == $_POST['dropdown_city']) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>
<option value="<?php echo $key ?>" <?php echo $selected ?>>
<?php echo $value ?>    </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
  </li>
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: please do not use `mysql_query` anymore. Its deprecated. Please check [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for more information and alternatives.

Comment: You can't do that in php+html you need to do that in javascript.

Comment: @jcubic yes ur right i have heard that alot but could u provide an example?

Comment: @michi have u read carfuly? i belive the question is obvious, i asked twice one in the title and the other above the code

Comment: @sandeepraju thank u i will check this later as its not related to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do ajax call to php file that populate another query and build your other select in jquery

```
</script>
$(function() {
    $('#dropdown_city').change(function() {
       $.getJSON('get_values.php', {city: $(this).val()}, function(data) {
           var dropdown = $('#dropdown_other').empty();
           $.each(data, function(i, item) {
              $('<option value="' + item[0] + '">' + item[1] +
                '</option>').appendTo(dropdown);
           });
       });
    });
});

</script>
...
<select name="dropdown_city" id="dropdown_city">

</select>
<select id="dropdown_other">
</select>
```

and in get_values.php you just return another select from database:

```
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['city']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM other_table WHERE city = $city", $con);
$options = array();
echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Comment: what is data in function(data)?


Also what is item in  function(i, item)?

Comment: what is data in function(data)? Also what is item in function(i, item)?

Comment: @adictee the ouput from the query `echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($result));` in php file `[[id, name], [id, name],...]` and item is `[id, name]`

Comment: what about the data in function(data)

Comment: @adictee first answer "the ouput from the query `echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($result));` in php file `[[id, name], [id, name],...]`"